# setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

My code returns "Uncaught reference error: y is not defined", because var y is defined inside a different function. (There is an html button that calls on the function p when pressed)

```
var x = 0;

function write5() {
   if (x <= 9) {
       document.write(5); 
       x += 1;
   }
  else {
   clearInterval(y);
  }
}
function p() {
  var y = setInterval(write5, 500);
}
```

But if I put the variable outside the function it starts immediately. How would I make the function print 5 10 times, starting only when the button is pressed and without returning an error?

Comment: Define the variable at the top(outside the function) with `var y;` then change the code inside the `p()` function to be just `y = ....`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare "y" outside the function, like this:

```
var x = 0;
var y = null;
function write5() {
   if (x <= 9) {
       document.write(5); 
       x += 1;
   }
  else {
   clearInterval(y);
  }
}
function p() {
  y = setInterval(write5, 500);
}
```